# Using person-time, instead of number of persons, for period pervalene

Tags: epidemiology, adjustment

Let's say we want to calculate the period prevalence of Type-1 diabetes (assume treatment is always necessary) during the last year in a tourist city with highly dynamic population (a lot of in/out).

The only data source is pharmacy records. Cases are defined as persons with >= 1 diabetes prescription dispensed at the pharmacy.

The total number of people who lived for >= 1 day during that year is **10,000**. The overall prevalence was **4.0%**.

But from those,

- **7000** people spent >= 1 month,  among whom the prevalence was **4.9%**.
- **3000** people spent < 1 month, among whom the prevalence was **2.0%**.

Assume that the more period a person with diabetes spends in this city, the higher chance (s)he will go to pharmacy and receive medications.

If we want to estimate the real number of diabetics who lived here, the overall prevalence of 4.0% will underestimate it.

To more accurately estimate the period prevalence where people vary with length of follow-up, it is possible to adjust the prevalence for the period people lived in the city, as follows?

```
sum of (person-time) for people with >= 1 prescription
------------------------------------------------------
         sum of (person-time) for all people
```

Is this approach valid? Are additional assumptions or information needed?

Comment: Up to 50% of persons with diabetes use no medications. They're on diet and lifestyle treatment.

Comment: To make it simple, let's assume it is Type 1 diabetes (aka insulin dependent - I edited the question), i.e. assume treatment is always necessary.